# N'th coefficient of two taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion

So,  I'm taking a course in Analytic Combinatorics,  and the author asserts without proof that the n'th coefficient of $z^n$ for the taylor (Around 0) expansion, for nonnegative integer values of r in the following is
$$\frac {r!z^r}{(1-2z)^{r+1}}=\frac {r!2^n}{2^r}\binom{n}{r}$$
(I couldn't figure out how to do the normal notation for the n choose r binomial notation, if someone can fix and let me know how to do it I'd appreciate it!)

I'm not very familiar with taylor series, is this some common result/based on a trick I should know about,  or just taking a bunch of derivatives and noticing a pattern?

I only really need the results for r=1 and r=2 for my presentation,  but it'd be nice to know the general case.

(Context:  This number,  divided by $2^n$ gives the factorial moments of the bivariate generating function for the binomial distribution of length n and k heads)

Comment: Try \binom{n}{r} for the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r}$

Comment: Thanks! (adds to mental library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = 2z$ and examine the generating function of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^s}$. We know a couple of things (these are true as formal Tayler series, regardless of convergence issues):

$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)} = \sum_{k\geq 0} x^k
$$

$$
\frac{d^m}{dx^m} \frac{1}{(1-x)} = \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{d^m}{dx^m} x^k = \sum_{k\geq m}  k^{\underline{m}}x^{k-m} 
$$
where we use the "falling power" notation, for example,  $k^\underline{3} \equiv k(k-1)(k-2)$.

$$
\frac{ m!}{(1-x)^{m+1}} =  \sum_{k\geq m}  k^{\underline{m}}x^{k-m} = \sum_{j\geq 0} (j+m)^{\underline{m}}x^j
$$
$$
\frac{1 }{(1-x)^{m+1}} =  \sum_{j\geq 0} \frac{(j+m)^{\underline{m}}}{m!}x^j = \sum_{j\geq 0} \binom{j+m}{j}x^j 
$$
Now let's replace $x$ by $2z$ and $m$ by $r$ to get
$$
\frac{z^r }{(1-2z)^{r+1}} =  \sum_{j\geq 0}  2^j \binom{j+r}{j}z^{j+r} 
$$
Finally substitute $n=j+r$ and note that $\binom{n}{n-r} = \binom{n}{r}$ and multiply both sides by $r!$ to get the desired relation.